# Is there a way to make this Kotlin code more clean?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code but I am convinced that it could be simpler/more elegant

```kotlin
package org.example

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped

@ApplicationScoped
object CanceledRequestsHandler {
  var identifiers = setOf<String>()

  fun add(id: String){
    var mutableIdentifiers = identifiers.toMutableList()
    mutableIdentifiers.add(id)
    this.ids = mutableIds.toSet()
  }
}
```

I wanted to limit the mutability. Any suggestions t improve my code?

Comment: Are you sure all your variable names are correct? It looks like you have 'identifiers' in one place and 'ids' in another, and 'mutableIdentifiers' in one place and 'mutableIds' in another. (I'm assuming those don't refer to something outside of the example code.)

Comment: A couple additional comments. Although I know this isn't the code you want to stick with, 'mutableIdentifiers' can be `val` rather than `var`. As for your question, is the intent to keep users of the object from modifying 'identifiers' directly? If so, I'll point out that since 'identifiers' is `var`, anyone can simply assign a new set to it and modify it that way. So unless I'm missing something, if the goal is to prevent direct modification from outside the object, what you have now doesn't seem to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to limit the mutability

Converting immutable collection to mutable on each data mutation is not a limitation of mutablility, it's just overhead. The worst here is that property is declared as mutable (`var`). This design may lead to data loss in multi-thread case.

If data mutation is unavoidable, then it's better to have mutable (concurrent in multi-thread case) data collection with immutable property (`val`).

Even better way to limit mutability will be using a mutable data structure only for a short initialization period, and then freezing it into immutable (see [buildSet](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/build-set.html)), but I'm not sure that this approach is applicable in your case.

Comment: Does it help to make the property private?

Comment: For limiting mutability? No, it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: If a property is private, it is not accessible from outside. Thus if it's `var` it will only be  modified within the class. What's wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: @Giant8: Keep in mind that it's not `var` vs `val` that determines whether you can mutate the set. There's at least 3 things to consider. `var` vs `val` determines/affects whether the value of the property itself can be changed - for example, in this case, using `var' allows you to replace the set entirely with a new set. Mutable vs immutable determines/affects whether the container itself can be modified. And visibility determines/affects who can access the container and in what way (and you're right that making it private is one way to control when and how changes are made).

Comment: @Giant8 If you make it `private`, then how these added values will be consumed?
You'll have to write a separate method/add another visible property with custom getter. Actually, it may be a good idea, if it return a freezed version of your mutable collection:
```private val _ids = mutableSetOf<String>();
val ids get() = _ids.toSet()
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a more elegant way! Try this script file (`.kts`) with `kotlinc` (or you can run it within IDEA):

```
object CanceledRequestsHandler {
  var ids = setOf<String>()

  override fun toString(): String = ids.toString()

  fun add(id: String){
    ids = ids + id
  }
}

System.err.println(CanceledRequestsHandler);
CanceledRequestsHandler.add("foo");
CanceledRequestsHandler.add("bar");
System.err.println(CanceledRequestsHandler);
```

A bit of explanation:

- The + operator can be applied to collections, and works as one might expect -- returns a new collection (see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-plus-minus.html).
- I'm not sure what your separate `identifiers` variable was, but you can use a single `var` that contains an `immutable` `Set` to do your job here.

As a commenter and the accepted answer point out, there's more you can do. If you're trying to limit mutability entirely to `add()`, you can lock this down further, with something like this:

```
object CanceledRequestsHandler {
  private var _ids = mutableSetOf<String>()

  val ids
    get() = _ids.toSet()

  override fun toString(): String = ids.toString()

  fun add(id: String) {
    _ids.add(id)
  }
}

System.err.println(CanceledRequestsHandler);
CanceledRequestsHandler.add("foo");
CanceledRequestsHandler.add("bar");
System.err.println(CanceledRequestsHandler);
// Below line does not compile
// CanceledRequestsHandler.ids.add("baz")
```

Now the only way the `ids` property can change is via the `add()` method.